# Ruby: sorting an array of arrays excluding 1st row

Tags: ruby, arrays, enumeration

Having the following array

```
[["Date", "Value"], ["2014-09-25", 0], ["2014-09-23", 1], ["2014-09-22", 0], ["2014-09-24", 2]]
```

How can I sort the array excluding the first row from the sorting?

Comment: excluding `["Date", "Value"]` ? right ?

Comment: Yes, excluding `["Date", "Value"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
[arr[0]].concat(arr[1..arr.length].sort)
```

where arr is your array

demo :

```
2.1.1 :001 > arr = [["Date", "Value"], ["2014-09-25", 0], ["2014-09-23", 1], ["2014-09-22", 0], ["2014-09-24", 2]]
 => [["Date", "Value"], ["2014-09-25", 0], ["2014-09-23", 1], ["2014-09-22", 0], ["2014-09-24", 2]] 
2.1.1 :002 > [arr[0]].concat(arr[1..arr.length].sort)
 => [["Date", "Value"], ["2014-09-22", 0], ["2014-09-23", 1], ["2014-09-24", 2], ["2014-09-25", 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
ary = [["Date", "Value"], ["2014-09-25", 0], ["2014-09-23", 1], ["2014-09-22", 0], ["2014-09-24", 2]]

header = ary.shift
ary.sort.unshift header
#=> [["Date", "Value"], ["2014-09-22", 0], ["2014-09-23", 1], ["2014-09-24", 2], ["2014-09-25", 0], ["Date", "Value"]]
```